# How to update pivot data

Tags: octobercms

After updating to the latest stable build, I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when updating pivot data.

I have an ajax handler that updates the product quantity in the order pivot table like this:

```
foreach (input('quantity') as $id => $quantity) {
    $order->products()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['quantity' => $quantity]);
}
```

This successfully updates the data in the pivot table and everyting looks good.

Now I refresh the model so the data would be up-to-date:

```
$order = $order->fresh();
```

And now for the strange part. Can someone explain to me, why this returns the old pivot value:

```
$order->products->first()->pivot->quantity;
```

And this returns the updated value:

```
$order->products()->first()->pivot->quantity;
```

Previously the first one returned the new value too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the `fresh()` function with the relationship name:

```
$order = $order->fresh(['products']);
```

Not sure why it worked before though